# Make a web service call in php

Tags: php, ruby, web-services, httpresponse, httpsession

So i have this working in ruby and i want to be able to do this in php. I am using the wamp server if that matters.

Here's the ruby method:

```
def response(url, body)
 uri = URI(url)

 request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
 request.body = body

 http_session = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)
 http_session.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == "https")
 http_session.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
 response = http_session.request(request)

 return response.body
end
```

I tried looking up other questions and this is where that got me:

```
$request_info = array();
$REQUEST_BODY = 'request body';

$full_response = @http_post_data(
    'url',
    $REQUEST_BODY,
    array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
            'SOAPAction' => 'HotelAvail',
        ),
        'timeout' => 60,

    ),
    $request_info
);

$response_xml = new SimpleXMLElement(strstr($full_response, '<?xml'));

foreach ($response_xml->xpath('//@HotelName') as $HotelName) {
    echo strval($HotelName) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: "I tried looking up other questions and this is where that got me." Okay, do you have a question?

Comment: The php code doesnt work. it doesnt show an error on the page though so im not sure whats wrong

Comment: you are not seeing an error because you have suppressed them. get rid of the @ sign before @http_post_data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http_post_data` depends on pecl_http.  Unless you must use http_post_data, cURL is probably installed by default on your WAMP server.

The code below is just an example; I haven't tested it but you get the idea:

```
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8',
    'SOAPAction' => 'HotelAvail',
);

$ch = curl_init($server_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$full_response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```